# Combine two each_with_object iterators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two methods doing almost exactly the same thing. I'd like to combine them into a single method to make them DRY.

```
  def build_training_organization_filters
    @dive_centers.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |obj, counts| counts[obj.training_organizations.first.short_name] += 1 }
  end

  def build_dive_center_type_filters
    @dive_centers.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |obj, counts| counts[obj.dive_center_type] += 1 }
  end
```

The output is eventually going to be JSON output like this:

`{ training_org_filter: <data>, dive_center_filter: <data> }`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've been staring at it for 40 minutes trying to wrap my head around how I can pass in multiple hashes to obj or dynamically chain methods based on parameters I pass into the method, but I don't even know where to begin...

Comment: It's unclear for me what you're asking.

Comment: I'm going to have about 15 different `.each_with_object` methods to count the number of instances 15 different elements exist in my database. Every single method is going to be exactly like the two above, except they will call different methods on `obj`. I was hoping for a way to write a single method `build_filters` instead of like 15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common part seems to be:

```
@dive_centers.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |obj, counts| counts[...] += 1 }
```

With `...` being

```
obj.training_organizations.first.short_name
```

and

```
obj.dive_center_type
```

Both of the above depend on `obj`, so we can extract the common part into a separate method and use `yield` to fetch the key from the caller:

```
def count_by
  @dive_centers.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| h[yield(o)] += 1 }
end
```

i.e. we provide the specific part by passing a block:

```
def build_training_organization_filters
  count_by { |center| center.training_organizations.first.short_name }
end

def build_dive_center_type_filters
  count_by { |center| center.dive_center_type }
end
```

Comment: LOL, it’s funny how we found the exactly opposite parts to be _common_.

Answer (score 4):

```
def build(*properties)
  @dive_centers.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |obj, counts|
    index = properties.reduce(obj) { |o, m| o.public_send(m) }
    counts[index] += 1
  end
end
```

And call it like:

```
build(:dive_center_type)
build(:training_organizations, :first, :short_name)
```

Comment: this didn't work, unfortunately. I like how concise it is.

Comment: It's giving  me a type error <DiveCenter...> is not a symbol nor integer

Comment: `properties.reduce(obj) { |o, m| o.public_send(m) }` works, though.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Arity 2. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not use `each_with_object` it seems like another viable option if you are using ruby >= 2.4. This uses `Enumerable#group_by` and `Hash#transform_values` although it does require multiple loops which is less desirable.

```
 def count_by(*chain)
    @dive_centers.group_by do |obj| 
      chain.reduce(obj) {|o,m| o.public_send(m)}
    end.transform_values(&:count)
 end
```

Usage

```
count_by(:dive_center_type)
count_by(:training_organizations, :first, :short_name)
```

Usage is the same as @mudasobwa's answer (mostly because signature and reduction was stolen as well.)